# Symfony, can't chain getter methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Symfony 6
Doctrine 3

**Titelmeta Entity Class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use DateTime;

/**
 * Titelmeta
 *
  
  …

 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Titelmeta
{
    …
    
    /**
     * @var \Isbn
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ISBN_mobi", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Isbn")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ISBN_mobi", referencedColumnName="isbn")
     * })
     */
    private $isbnMobi;

    …

    public function getIsbnMobi(): ?Isbn
    {
        return $this->isbnMobi;
    }


}
```

**Isbn Entity Class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Isbn
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="isbn", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="isbn", columns={"isbn"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Isbn
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $isbn;

    …

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getIsbn();
    }

    public function getIsbn(): ?string
    {
        return $this->isbn;
    }

    …

}
```

I have an result object named $record

dump($record);

> App\Entity\Titelmeta {#901 ▼
> -isbnMobi: "97812345678"
> }

dump($record->getIsbnMobi()->getIsbn());

> App\Entity\Titelmeta::getIsbnMobi(): Return value must be of type
> ?App\Entity\Isbn, string returned

[image]

I don't get it. Can someone please help.

Comment: can you provide more information about if the data in the database are correct? as you can see there is a typehint in the return like ?Isbn, so this error happens when you try to access to the record and this relation doesnt exists.

Answer (score 1):

The isbnMobi should NOT be a number. In an ORM if you have relations between objects, it should always be `null`, an actual object, a proxy of an object or in case of multiple objects, a (proxy) collection. Since your isbnMobi is not an object but a number, this implies your ORM was misconfigured ...

The Titlemeta entity should NOT have `@ORM\Column` on the `isbnMobi` property. That information is handled via `ManyToOne`'s `JoinColumn`. **Remove it** and you should be fine.

The `Column`s attributes can mostly be assigned to the `JoinColumn` instead. By default, the database column type must (automatically) match the referenced database column type, with `nullable` being the notable exception.

Also, the `@var` on that same property should be just `Isbn` not `\Isbn`, since the leading `\` would mean it's in the root namespace.

If you're using php 8, use attributes instead of annotations and add the typehints to the property instead of `@var` (not technically binding).

Comment: The entities were solely written by Symfony itself with "php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity" - I my self am not very good at writing them by myself.

Comment: And writing to Titelmeta with setter  methods works without problems.

Comment: Damn. Just removing the @ORM\Column line solved it. Thank you so much. But honestly, I have no idea why.

Comment: because, on an object the property cannot be both an int (column) and an object (relation partner(s)), have to decide. doctrine tools aren't always super reliable, sadly.